# Testing akka-http route that completes with infinite stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an akka-http route which is returning a `Source` containing an infinite stream of entities. How can I test that using the route testkit? I'd like to inspect just the first n elements of the stream, but I've taken a look at the testkit code, and it looks like there's no direct way to access the `Source` in the response. It's always converted to a sequence of `ByteString`s, which in my case just causes a `TimeoutException`, since the stream never terminates.

For reference, the problem can be reproduced with a route looking something like this:

```
case class Bar(wibble: String, wobble: String)

path("stream") {
  get {
    complete {
      import JsonSupport._
      implicit val streamingSupport = EntityStreamingSupport.json()
      Source.unfold(1) { i =>
        Thread.sleep(10)
        Some((i + 1, Bar(i.toString, (i + 1).toString)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `JsonSupport` ??

Comment: `JsonSupport` is defined as:


    object JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
      implicit val barFormat = jsonFormat2(Bar)
    }

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html ??

Comment: But this streaming is not mean for something like an infinite stream. HTTP in its standard from must define a time-out for long-running requests. And thus Akka-http does it. If you need an "infinite-stream" then you should use web-sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like whenever you're accessing the response and the entity within the boundaries of the testkit, the testkit it's going to try and extract it fully.

You can check out private method `awaitAllElements` in [RouteTestResultComponent](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/RouteTestResultComponent.scala) class for further insight.

You could try simply using akka-streams combinators instead. I reckon it wouldn't bloat your test code too much. Example below:

```
def firstNElements(n: Int) = Source.single(yourRequest)
  .via(RouteResult.route2HandlerFlow(route))
  .flatMapConcat(_.entity.dataBytes)
  .take(n)
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
  .futureValue

// assertions
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - calling `response` blocks until all the elements are received, which leads to a TimeoutException for an infinite stream

Comment: you're right, I hadn't checked the testkit code properly. I have amended the response suggesting something else..

Comment: That's does the trick - thanks! I changed `RouteResult.route2HandlerFlow' to 'Route.handlerFlow' for conciseness, and due to the formatting of the response (with "," separators on their own line), I had to take the first 6 elements to get 3 serialized entities (and converted used ByteString.utf8String to convert to something more easily parseable), but this is exactly what I was looking for.